# Text placed is center with using center widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Question: No center widget is used, still the title "Daily" is the center. How?

The code provided below is the of the UI of the app as shows in the image.
CarouselSlider is used to slide horizontally.

***Code:***

```
CarouselSlider(
                items: [
                Column(
                children: [
                Container(
                child: Text("Daily", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                ),
                Expanded(
                   child: SingleChildScrollView(
                   child: Container(
                   margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                   child: Text(data['daily'], textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17 )),
                                                  )),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          Column(
                                            children: [
                                              Container(
                                                child: Text("Weekly", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
                                              ),
                                              Expanded(
                                                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                                                    child: Text(data['weekly'], textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17 )),
                                                  )),
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                    
                                    options: CarouselOptions(
                                      
                                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height-300,                                      
                                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                                      initialPage: 0,
                                      aspectRatio: 16/9,
                                      autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
                                      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                                      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                                      viewportFraction: 1,
                                    ),
                                  );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change those with columns axisAlignments

```
Column(
   crossAxisAlignment : CrossAxisAlignment.start
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This happened because of the default setting of `Column` and `crossAxisAlignment` which by default set to `center`, you can override it like this:

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // <=== add this
    children: [
      Container(
        child: Text("Daily",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20)),
      ),
      ...
    ],
  ),
```

more about [crossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html)